# is there an option for FitResiduals in FindFit?

Tags: fitting

I know this option exists in NonlinearModelFit and probably in other fit models as well but for some reason the best result i get is with FindFit.

Regards 
Doron

Comment: Can you post your example?  `FindFit` is an older function, having been introduced in v5.  `NonlinearModelFit` and `LinearModelFit` were introduced more recently in v7 and (I'm guessing here) are probably the functions that will be maintained in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know. The only difference (in terms of fitted models) between `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit` is that `NonlinearModelFit` allows for extraction of additional information about the fitting - for example `model["FitResiduals"]`. `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit` yield equivalent models. The best-fit function from `NonlinearModelFit[data,form,pars,vars]` is the same as the result from `FindFit[data,form,pars,vars]`. So you should be completely satisfied with `NonlinearModelFit` and if you see any differences between results of fitting - it must be due to some discrepancy. If you can show here 2 examples where `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit` return different fits - I'd be very curious.